# Логические операторы c++

Tags: c++, логические-выражения

Начал учить с++, на теме логических операторов после пары минут экспериментов наткнулся на то, что есть некоторые нелогичные моменты у логических операторов. А именно - как-будто в с++ есть три возможных boolean значения.

Интересные моменты моих экспериментов:

```
true == 5 дает false (хотя всё true, что не 0)
false == 5 дает false (тут было бы все нормально, если бы не предыдущее выражение)
true && 5 дает true (тут мой мозг взорвался, потому что оператор && возвращает true, если оба операнда - true, 
а два операнда не могут быть true, если один операнд != другой операнд (5 != true даст true), а всего существует только 2 варианта значения (true, false).
```

Как можно формализовать такие знания в какую-то систему, которую проще запомнить (ведь она должна быть, иначе смысла в логических выражений не будет, если они будут нелогичны)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто. Как thumb rule (ну, простое правило "на пальцах") - приведите разнородные типы в *арифметических* операциях к большему типу. Т.е. в

```
true == 5
```

не 5 приводится к `bool`, а `true` превращается в `int`, равный 1. Сравнение дает результат `bool`, но его операнды - арифметические типы.

Там, где оператор для *логических операндов* (`&&`, `||`) - приводим операнды к типу `bool`.

Вот и все.

Answer (score 4):

У вас интерференция между топиками "Типы данных и из преобразование" и "Логические операторы".

В первом случае, ваше `true` приводится к типу `int` и происходит сравнение `1==5` с понятным итогом `false`.

Во втором случае, `0==5` с аналогичным итогом

В последнем случае, приведения типов первого операнда не будет, зато приведется тип второго операнда, 5 превратится в `true`

Для того, чтобы не путаться, не пытайтесь сравнивать переменные разных типов. Всегда делайте явное приведение при помощи `static_cast<>`

Answer (score 1):

### Это следствие правил конвертации в C/C++

Подробнее по пунктам:

```
true == 5
```

Тут `true` сконвертился в `int`, и получилось сравнение `1 == 5` , что равно `false`

```
false == 5
```

Тут `false` сконвертился в `int`, и получилось сравнение `0 == 5` , что равно `false`

```
true && 5
```

Тут `5` сконвертился в `true`, и получилось `true && true` , что равно `true`

Comment: и как же  одно значение(5)  конвертируется в  другое значение(true )?...  По моему правильнее, что    bool() инициализируется этим значением, в результате выдавая true